# Appium Automation Using Robotframework ,Click Element/Click Button Issue

Tags: android, appium, robotframework

When i am trying to Click Element \Click Button I'm getting Below Error:

> Starting test: Sai.AB
>   20180118 14:18:43.625 :  INFO : Slept 2 seconds
>   20180118 14:18:43.626 :  INFO : Clicking element 'id=slide-skip-btn'.
>   20180118 14:19:20.626 :  INFO : 
>   20180118 14:19:20.650 :  FAIL : ValueError: Element locator 'id=slide-skip-btn' did not match any elements.
>   Ending test:   Sai.AB

Comment: I think you are not really locating your element... "Element locator 'id=slide-skip-btn' **did not match any elements**"

Comment: FAIL : TypeError: exceptions must be old-style classes or derived from BaseException, not unicode i am getting above error also